# Div to the right of a float is causing a horizontal scroll

Tags: css, html, css-float, width

I have a div which is floating to the left with a menu in it and another div to the right which is filling the rest of the space, the problem is, the div on the right is set to 100% but is going off to the right of the page and creating an unwanted scroll. I think the cause is the left-margin I have put on it to allow for the left floating div. Is there a way to make the right div fill the rest of the space without creating a horizontal scroll but so that I can also align things left: 0px against the edge of the float.
I have put the page onto one of my other domains so you can see:
http://aspiresupportandhousing.com/cleanserve/

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="lp_bt">
    <div id="logo_container_s">
    </div>
    <div id="menu_container_s">
      <nav id="secondary_nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Our Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cleaning</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="left_panel">
    <div id="logo_container">
    </div>
    <div id="menu_container">
      <nav id="primary_nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Our Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cleaning</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="right_panel">
    <div id="main_container">
      <div id="title">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 1000px;
}

* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    color: #000000;
}

/* Hidden */
#lb_bt {
    height: 30px;
width: 30px;
left: 30px;
}

#logo_container_s { 
left: -150px;
width: 150px;
height: 42px;
position: absolute;
background: url(logo.jpg);
z-index: 3000;
}

#menu_container_s {
left: -150px;
height: 400px;
width: 150px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 3000;
}
/* End Hidden */

/* Left Panel */
#left_panel {
height: 100%;
width: 150px;
float: left;
background-color: #26609E;
z-index: 2000;
}

#logo_container {
width: 150px;
height: 42px;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
position: relative;
background: url(logo.jpg);
z-index: 3000;
}

#menu_container {
height: 400px;
width: 150px;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
position: relative;
}

ul {
list-style: none;
text-align: left;
border-top: solid 1px #002954;
}

ul li {
display: list-item; 
}

ul li a:link, ul li a:visited {
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: normal;
width: 800;
color: #FFFFFF;
line-height: 38px;
margin: 0px 10px;
padding: 0px 5px 8px 0px;
text-align: left;
text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a:hover, ul li a:active {
color: #2593C1;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 280px) and (max-width: 800px) {
body {
    background: none rgba(161, 220, 254, 0.4);  
}

#left_panel {
    left: -150px;
    position: absolute;
}

#lp_bt {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: url(menu.jpg);
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

#lp_bt:hover {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    background: none #26609E;
}

#lp_bt:hover #secondary_nav {
    display: list-item; 
}

#lp_bt:hover #logo_container_s {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

#lp_bt:hover #menu_container_s {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: relative;
}
}
/* End Left Panel */

/* Right Panel */
#right_panel {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin-left: 150px;
background: url(bg.jpg) no-repeat top left fixed;
background-size: cover;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
}

#main_container {
width: 700px;
height: 50%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: auto;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
}

#title {
width: 600px;
height: 104px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
top: 30px;
background: url(title.png) no-repeat center center;
position: relative;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 280px) and (max-width: 800px) {
#right_panel {
    background: none;
}
}
```

Comment: A prime example of a question that should come with a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ;)

Comment: I have never used this before but I will give it a go and post the results, I have also put a link to temporary link where I have uploaded the files to see a live version of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Scroll Is caused beacuse yo have a `margin-left` for your

> #right_panel

You have three solutions wich envolve make some changes in CSS for the `#right_panel`

- One use method `calc()` to set the width:

  ```
  #right_panel {
     width: calc( 100% - 150px);
  }
  ```
- Two change your `z-index` value and delete `margin-left`:

  ```
  #right_panel {
     width:100%;
     margin-left:0;
     z-index:-1;
  }
  ```
- Three use `box-sizing` and `padding` instead of `margin`:

  ```
  #right_panel {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding-left:150px;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
  }
  ```

Comment: That is amazing, thank you so much, I have not been using CSS long and I'm still learning but that is something which is going to come in very handy. Is my coding looking good for a beginner?

Comment: It looks good try to keep it simple ... check the edit answer

Comment: so fast for me :D. Calc don't work on my Codepen. We can use this property on the specific file ?

Comment: I'm guessing this is not the simple way around what I am trying to do?

I thought that if I used padding instead of margin, the background image wouldn't fit as well in the panel due to the div starting flush on the left? or does it make no difference?

What does the box sizing do?

Comment: @ColoO take care with calc is includede with CSS3 check compatibility http://caniuse.com/calc ... And Tristan box-sizing helps to keep thw widht you define intact if you add padding or border beacuse in general those values increase the total width... if you add padding your bg image isn't affected

Comment: Np a good article about calc http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/

Comment: Oh ok, that's really handy to know, I keep changing the padding and then have to calculate the new width to give me the desired overall width.
Create a div (diva) and put a background on it and then create a div (divb) which is 20px wide and coloured, then you put both divs left: 0 with divb on top, it will cover part of the bg on diva, if you add padding to diva, there will be no change, if you add a margin to diva then it will push the div out so that the bg is all visible... do you get what I mean now?

Answer (score 0):

Seen as though `#left_panel` and `#right_panel` are positioned absolutely, you can simply remove the negative margin form `#left_panel`:

```
#left_panel {
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

... then remove the 100% width from `#right_panel` and position it thusly:

```
#right_panel {
    top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:150px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pz7PP/

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I managed to solve it with the answer given by Danko but I will keep this in mind for the future. One thing though, the left panel is a float and I saw you put that both panels are positioned absolutely so are floats positioned absolutely? (I am a bit of a noob to CSS, still learning)

Comment: @TristanD27 floats on absolutely positioned elements are entirely redundant as absolute elements are taken out of 'the flow' and behave like are a totally separate layer. Floats are positioned relative to their parent but remain in the flow (although they might appear otherwise). Here is [an article about floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) that may be useful.

Comment: That is what I thought but I was questiong it because you said "#left_panel and #right_panel are positioned absolutely" but;  

#left_panel { height: 100%; width: 150px; float: left; background-color: #26609E; z-index: 2000; }

Comment: you later add `#left_panel {left: -150px; position: absolute;}` within you media-query

Answer (score 0):

You need use CSS position.

A little example
[Codepen](http://codepen.io/ColoO/pen/vtHdg)

CSS

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;}


#divleft {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;bottom:0;left:0;
 width:250px;
 background: red;
}

#divright {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 left:250px;
 right:0;
 background: green;
}
```

Comment: The reason I cannot do that is because my left_panel is a float and needs to be static but the right_panel needs to be able to scroll vertically if I need it to, please correct me if I am wrong (as I keep explaining to people, I am a noob to CSS) but I don't think this way would allow the right hand to scroll vertically if needed. Thanks for the answer though, I can see that coming in very useful for other projects.

Comment: just put overflow:auto on #divright if you need to scroll one div ^^. The #divleft will be static but if there are much of content in your divleft, the scroll will appear. (sorry for my bad english ^^' )

Comment: It sounds like this would of been a much simpler solution to what I am trying to achieve, have you previewed it in the browser and tried shrinking the window width? You will notice the menu disappear and a small icon appear, hover on that and it comes back, have I done this a complicated way? Or have I done it well? It's no problem, sorry for my lack of CSS knowledge >.<

Comment: Media query is a good solution for the different screen size and u will be used the media query with css position too. But (=D) we used to have a menu that is 100% of the width. And it would be more than when you click on the button menu does not disappear. I think it would be better to use javascript rather than ownership: hover. We're getting away from your question. ^ ^

Comment: I see your point but the thing is, I prefer to do as much as possible with CSS (for now) because I don't know any JS and I'm still new to CSS so I would rather get comfortable with CSS before trying to learn bits of JS too, my poor brain will explode if I try to learn too much at once, too much code to remember >.< I will start on the JS soon, don't worry. Thanks for the help, it has helped a help and gave me ideas for new projects, I'll find a use for it with my next client no doubt.